# kops etcd ebs volume size change

Tags: aws, kubernetes

I am running kubernetes on AWS using KOPs.  i want to reduce the EBS-etcd volumes which would get attached to the Master node. 
is there a way to do this???

```
# kops edit  cluster --name=kubernetes.summimak.online --state=s3://kubernetes.summimak.online

EBSVolume/a.etcd-events.kubernetes.summimak.online
        AvailabilityZone        ap-south-1a
        VolumeType              gp2
        SizeGB                  20
        Encrypted               false
        Tags                    {k8s.io/etcd/events: a/a, k8s.io/role/master: 1, Name: a.etcd-events.kubernetes.summimak.online, KubernetesCluster: kubernetes.summimak.online}

  EBSVolume/a.etcd-main.kubernetes.summimak.online
        AvailabilityZone        ap-south-1a
        VolumeType              gp2
        SizeGB                  20
        Encrypted               false
        Tags                    {k8s.io/etcd/main: a/a, k8s.io/role/master: 1, Name: a.etcd-main.kubernetes.summimak.online, KubernetesCluster: kubernetes.summimak.online}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add volume size

```
volumeSize: 8
```

after name

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @SurajSingh's answer (I can't comment), the location of the `volumeSize` definition
should be `spec.etcdClusters[].etcdMembers[].volumeSize`.
See [the API](https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/cluster_spec/#etcdclusters).

In other words, when you use `kops edit cluster`
you might make your `etcdClusters` block look something like this:

```
etcdClusters:
- cpuRequest: 200m
  etcdMembers:
  - instanceGroup: master-ap-south-1a
    name: a
    volumeSize: 8
  memoryRequest: 100Mi
  name: main
- cpuRequest: 100m
  etcdMembers:
  - instanceGroup: master-ap-south-1a
    name: a
    volumeSize: 8
  memoryRequest: 100Mi
  name: events
```

if you wanted 8Gi for each of the two volumes.

At the moment there is [an open issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/8993) requesting an `--etcd-volume-size` flag for `kops create cluster`, but so far the comments sound negative.